# For a scalar product, is it enough for me to say that $\langle A,A\rangle=\|A\|^2$ therefore $\langle A,A\rangle\geq0$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following scalar product defined as : $ \langle A , B \rangle = \operatorname{tr}(A^T, B)$.

I want to verify the 4<sup>th</sup> axiom of scalar products ($\langle A, A \rangle \geq 0$).

Is it enough for me to use this reasoning: We know that $ \langle A, A \rangle = \|A\|^2$ therefore $\langle A, A \rangle$ is $\geq 0$. If it's wrong or not enough how would I go about to prove that the propriety is verified (Because I know in advance that it's a scalar product)

Comment: "we know that..." who knows this? how?

Comment: If you know in advance that this is a scalar product, what is that you are trying to prove?

Comment: I know because I checked the answer, I want to know why and how come.

Comment: The answer to what question? If it is a scalar product, then $\langle A,A\rangle\ge0$ by definition of scalar product. If you want to know why this is a scalar product, you need to verify if it is a scalar product.

Comment: Yes, I am doing the process of verifying why it's a scalar product. You have to check 4 Axioms and I am checking the 4th one. The problem here is I want to know if what I did to check the 4th axiom is valid or not. Assume that I am doing this while not knowing the answer.

Comment: About your last edit: what do you mean by "$A^2$ can be written as $\langle A,A\rangle$"? This is false and absurd.

Comment: You did not say what you did to check the 4th axiom. You said that you just assumed it to be true (without checking).

Comment: Ok, how do you check? This what I want know.

Comment: "I know because I checked the answer" -- well, if you *know* that this is a scalar product, then you know that all the axioms are satisfied, and you know why. Otherwise you do not know, despite checking the answer. (I am mean, but i am trying to clarify the situation.)

Comment: You don't know that $\langle A, A\rangle = ||A||^2$.  Once you verify that $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle$ is an inner product, then you get to define $||A||$ by $\langle A, A\rangle = ||A||^2$.

Comment: What does inner product mean?

Comment: @Dr.Stone, *inner product* is another term for scalar product.

Comment: You do not need to, *scalar product* is a better term IMO.

Comment: I said "inner product" because I wasn't sure if a "scalar product" requires positive-definiteness.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your matrices have real-valued entries, $a_{ij} \in \mathbb{R}$, you could compute $tr(A^T.A)$ to get
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}^2,
\end{equation}
which is obviously greater than or equal to zero.

For example, if $A$ were the following 2x2 matrix
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{bmatrix}

then $A^T$ would be

\begin{bmatrix}
a & c\\
b & d
\end{bmatrix}

and $A^T.A$ would be

\begin{bmatrix}
a^2+c^2 & ab+cd\\
ab+cd & b^2+d^2
\end{bmatrix}

and so $tr(A^T.A)=a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2$.

Comment: Why its valid to take the sum of the square elements of the matrix (A^T) *(A) ? I would like just more details on how you got from point A to point B in your solution.

Comment: I think the problem of Dr.Stone is more deep than simple inexperience with linear algebra.

Comment: The trace is the sum of the diagonal elements of a matrix, then why do you square each elements before adding them? What is the (reasoning/what allows you do this) behind this?

Comment: @Dr.Stone, try adding up the diagonal elements of $A^TA$.

Comment: Oh now I get it, it's really simple. Thanks. It's because A^T = A, isn't it?

Comment: $A^T$ is not necessarily $A$. I recommend that you try computing $A^T.A$ for an arbitrary 2x2 matrix, just to see what is going on here.

Comment: I meant the tr(A^T) = tr(A).

Comment: Yes, it is true that $tr(A^T)=tr(A)$.

Comment: But then how does an element of the diagonal of the matrix (A^T * A) is a^2 ? Knowing that tr(AB)  != tr(A) * tr(B).

Comment: If $A=[[a,b],[c,d]]$, then $A^T=[[a,c],[b,d]]$. Then the $(1,1)$ entry of $A^T.A$ is $a^2+c^2$ and the $(2,2)$ entry is $b^2+d^2$. Computing the trace of $A^T.A$ then gives you $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2$.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was asking for. Can you put it in your post so it can be clear for others that may be in the same situation than me?